# Address sizes in Intel i5

Tags: memory-management, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

My cpuinfo file says that my processor has address sizes as 39 bits physical, and 48 bits virtual. This has got me into some confusion.

Mine is a 64 bit machine. From what I understand, this is the word size of my machine. That is, it will fetch data from memory in chunks of 8 bytes. Also, a 64 bit machine means that the CPU can address 2^64 byte addressable locations, which is a lot. So, manufacturers cut-down some of these lines.

Here are the questions:

1. If the CPU only generates logical addresses, then what is the need for having 39 bits physical address size.
2. When we say that the CPU can access 2^64 bytes, do we mean Physical memory or the virtual memory?
3. I read somewhere that a 64 bit machine has size of its registers as 64 bits, and a 32 bit machine has 32 bit registers. Is this the case?

I think I have confused myself terribly, and need some help. Any other information on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, all of those are oversimplifications.  For one thing, your CPU fetches data from memory 64 **bytes** at a time (whole cache lines).  The core can read/write data from cache 16 or 32 bytes at a time (SSE or AVX vectors of 128b or 256b).  "word size" is nice in theory, but real CPUs have lots of different widths for different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why people are puzzled considering the number of academic questions posed on this board that suggest there is some mathematical relationship among address sizes.

The processor word size, physical address size, logical address size, and bus size are all independent to some degrees.

> If the CPU only generates logical addresses, then what is the need for having 39 bits physical address size.

The CPU translates logical addresses to physical addresses.

> When we say that the CPU can access 2^64 bytes, do we mean Physical memory or the virtual memory?

I could be either.

> I read somewhere that a 64 bit machine has size of its registers as 64 bits, and a 32 bit machine has 32 bit registers. Is this the case?

Generally this is true for general registers but special purpose registers may be a different size (e.g., floating point, control registers)

Answer (score 2):

There have been many occasions when a processor does not use all available bits for the generation of addresses.

In ancient times, the old MC68000 had 32 bit registers but only a 24 bit address bus.

For the i5 consider that a 64 bit address would control a mind boggling memory space of 17,179,869,184 gigabytes. A stupendously huge number even compared to the storage at Google or the NSA or the planet Earth.

The i5 designers, trim this insane number down to a more manageable 512 gigabytes of physical address space and 262,144 gigabytes of virtual address space.